# Ng If with a boolean - to change the title of a page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my page `Stock` I have several fields with a title named `Title 1`.

[image]

If I do a console.log I am on my first page !

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.currentPortfolio = this.shrd.getData('currentPortfolio');
    this.subPage = 'stocks';
    this.sectionTitle = "";
    this.pageTitle = "Options";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.optionsDropdownFilters.length; i++) {
        this.issuers.actionsGrouped[this.optionsDropdownFilters[i]] = [];
    }

    console.log("First page => Tile 1 : " + JSON.stringify(this.subPage = 'stocks'));
    this.initiate();
}
```

In Google Chrome I have this:
[image]

Now, I click on the button `Search` in my page `Stock`...
I want to change `Title1` to `Title2`.

[image]

If I do a console.log, I am on my second page

[image]

```
launchSearchSelected(t) {
    this.searched = true;
    this.dateNotValid = false;
    this.dateDoesntExist = false;
    if (this.search.equityDate.length == 0) {
        this.dateDoesntExist = true
    }
    if (t == 'A' && this.search.equityOptionCode > 0 && this.search.equityDate.length > 0) {
        this.launchSearchResult(t, this.search.equityOptionCode, this.search.equityDate);
    } else if (t == 'I' && this.search.indexOptionCode.length > 0 && this.search.indexDate.length > 0) {
        this.launchSearchResult(t, this.search.indexOptionCode, this.search.indexDate);
    }
    console.log("Second Page => Title 2 " + JSON.stringify(this.searched = true));
}
```

In my HTML, I don't understand how can I switch from one title to another with the boolean?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="subPage  === 'stocks' ">
   <div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between">
      <h1>Title 1  </h1>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow but do you know that your console logging code is setting the `subPage` variable? `JSON.stringify(this.subPage = 'stocks')` sets `this.subPage` to `'stocks'`. You're not testing the variable value; you are setting it!

Comment: @andrew: I have the solution, thanks again for your message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="subPage  === 'stocks' ">
   <ng-container *ngIf="spinners.search  === true ">
      <div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between">
         <h1>Title 1 </h1>
      </div>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="subPage  === 'stocks' ">
   <ng-container *ngIf="spinners.search  === false ">
      <div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between">
         <h1>Title 2 </h1>
         <button (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary"> Back
         </button>
      </div>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the best way to proceed is without more information, but if you just want to change the title based on the `this.subPage` variable having the value "*stocks*" or not (like it seems you are attempting), then you can do this:

```
<ng-container>
   <div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between">
      <h1 *ngIf="subPage == 'stocks'">Title 1</h1>
      <h1 *ngIf="subPage != 'stocks'">Title 2</h1>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```